# make enterprise app not uninstallable

Tags: android, root

I'm developing a enterprise app for my client. He got the Companys phones rooted, but he need an app where he can control the background. But the problem is, he dont want so the app can be uninstalled. I know that you can make the app an system app, but it can still be deactivated.. Also you can use device admin, but it can just get unregistered, and then uninstalled.. Any way to make the app uninstallable? Of course is the app only going to get installed on the Companys phones, and not released om google play. Ask if you dont understand my question..  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the manufacturer of the device, this might be possible.  I'm most familiar with Samsung devices.

On Samsung devices, there is a special SDK called Knox which has many useful APIs.  One of those allows you to disable uninstallation for any app you choose.  Even with this, the app could still be removed by a factory reset (but Knox can disable factory reset as well).

If you aren't on Samsung, it's possible that whatever manufacturer you use has a similar SDK, so you should look into it. If you are on Samsung, you will need access to the Knox SDK, which isn't free, but since you said this is for a client maybe he would be willing to pay?